# Data grid based on User input

Tags: jquery, mysql, google-docs

basically i have a Google sheet, in which visitors input their info and the sheet calculates the results based on data pulled from another sheet and shows their results. I would like to get out of Google and use Mysql and ask user to submit his data before displaying his results.

here is the link to the sheet if anyone wants to see and have an idea of what im talking about

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HZYGigk5jQrV0hxFdwAE7hLo7_zv-rotsZHWigT5I9U/edit#gid=0

Comment: it was a suggestion by the site. its actually google sheet

Comment: i need to move this out of google sheets and create a page that does the same. i have no idea where to even look for something like this. maybe there is a site i can hire someone to do it for me

Comment: well ias i have been saying, i dont know if you saw the sheet i  have. there are too many people logging in at the same time and it is hard for them cause each one has their own data to input. so  it would be better if i could host it as a website, have them input their data(yellow boxes), select building(green box and hit submit, to see the resulting data at bottom.)